# unable to call firebase function from angular: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.functions is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

It work previously but now i am encountering error, i tried to troubleshoot but still running out of idea..

So below is my Angular's service code:

```
  import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'; //the import

//the function 

  createUser(user){
    let createUserFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createUser')
    return createUserFunction(user)
  }
```

This is how i call the service from my component:

```
this.authService.createUser(this.user).then(newUser => {
  //some other logic
},error=>{
  console.log(error)
})
```

Below is my nodejs code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./keys/privatekey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://<project_id>.firebaseio.com'
});

exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    let newUser = {
        emailVerified: false
    }
    if (data.email && data.password) {
        newUser["email"] = data.email
        newUser["password"] = data.password
    }
    else {
        return {
            code: -1,
            msg: "email/password is missing"
        }
    }
    return admin.auth().createUser(newUser).then(userRecord => {
        console.log("successfully created new User: ", userRecord.uid, ", by: ", context.auth.uid)
        console.log(userRecord)
        return userRecord
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Failed to create user: ", error)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('Failed to create user', error);

    })
});
```

And below is the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.functions is not a function
```

or sometime is below error when i call another exported firebase function

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.functions is not a function
TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.functions is not a function
```

Please let me know if the given information is not sufficient to troubleshoot the problem. I also don have any idea what information i need to provide.

Comment: Check for name mismatch while calling functions.

Comment: i believe the function name is correct..